# Make FILE* struct map to a buffer?

Tags: c, file, buffer

I am working with some legacy code which uses something like this:

```
void store_data(FILE *file);
```

However, I don't want to store data on the disk, I want to store it in memory (`char *buf`). I could edit all of the code, but the code jumps all over the place and `fwrite` gets called on the file all over the place. So is there an easier way, for example that I can map a `FILE*` object to an (auto-growing) buffer? **I do not know the total size of the data before-hand.**

The solution has to be portable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this using only the facilities provided in the C standard.  The closest you can come is

```
FILE *scratch = tmpfile();
...
store_data(scratch);
...
/* after you're completely done calling the legacy code */
rewind(scratch);
buf = read_into_memory_buffer(scratch);
fclose(scratch);
```

This does hit the disk, at least potentially, but I'd say it's your best bet if you need wide portability and can't modify the "legacy code".

In POSIX.1-2008, there is [`open_memstream`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html), which does exactly what you want; however, this revision of POSIX is not yet widely adopted.  GNU libc (used on Linux and a few others) has it, but it's not available on OSX or the *BSDs as far as I know, and certainly not on Windows.

Comment: Pipes are not in the C standard either.  On Unix, yeah, you could have a pipe loop back to another thread in the same process that wrote to a memory buffer.  On Windows, you can theoretically do the same thing but I would expect it to be a source of unending grief, and even on Unix this strikes me as too much work for not that much gain over the `tmpfile` approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at `fmemopen` and `open_memstream`. They do something in the direction of what you want.

From the man page:

> The open_memstream() function opens a stream for writing to  a  buffer.
>   The  buffer is dynamically allocated (as with malloc(3)), and automati‐
>   cally grows as required.  After closing the stream, the  caller  should
>   free(3) this buffer.

Comment: According to the man page on my system, these functions conform to "POSIX.1-2008. These functions are not specified in POSIX.1-2001, and are not widely available on other systems."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a **good** idea, but it's an idea.

You can "redefine" fwrite using a macro.

```
#define fwrite(a, b, c) your_memory_write_function(a, b, c)
```

Then implement `memory_write_function` to write data to your auto growing buffer instead of a file.

You will need to call `store_data` with a pointer to something else though (not a pointer to `FILE`). But that's possible with **C** so you will have no issues there.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [fmemopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen).  If that's not available to you, then you could possibly use a named shared memory segment along with `fdopen()` to convert the file descriptor returned by `shm_open()` to a `FILE*`.

Comment: `fmemopen` does not auto-resize the memory buffer on write, so it doesn't meet the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

On what platform are you running? Can't you use tmpfs? If you open a file on tmpfs, is it not, from the point of view of the kernel, the same as a regular file, but written to memory?

Comment: The code has to be __portable__, I'm not running on any particular platform/OS (the big three is a good start though).

Comment: The big three? That must be FreeBSD, OpenBSD and NetBSD, right? ... Right?? ... (sound of crickets) ... oh, common guys...

Comment: @ninjalj You are *so* looking to start a flame war. But I think it's quite funny :-D